# Use python IP address to mask IP addresses

Tags: python, ip-address

I'm new to IP addresses, so forgive me if I'm using some terminology incorrectly.

I would like to take IP address and get their address with the final octet zeroed out. Similar, bitwise, to multiplying by 255.255.255.0.

With strings alone, this would do the job:

```
ip_address = '192.168.1.1'
octets = ip_address.split('.')
masked_address = '.'.join(octets[:-1]) + '.0'
```

However, I would like to be able to draw from different sources while creating the collection. Sometimes I have bytes representations of IP addresses, sometimes integer, sometimes string. Hence, it's easiest if I know how to do this on a collection where the data is stored as python ipaddress.IPAddress (4 and 6...) objects. The workflow would be: take ip addresses from different sources, turn to python IP objects, merge collections, transfrom to IP/24 type addresses. But I don't see anything in the `ipaddress` docs that makes clear how to do the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating ip addresses is just bitwise math.

If you have an address in an `ipaddress.IPv4Address` object, you can zero out the last octet by writing:

```
>>> x = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1')
>>> y = ipaddress.ip_address(int(x) & 0xffffff00)
>>> y
IPv4Address('192.168.1.0')
```

Where `0xffffff00` is just the equivalent of `255.255.255.0`. You could of course write:

```
>>> mask = int(ipaddress.ip_address('255.255.255.0'))
>>> y = ipaddress.ip_address(int(x) & mask)
```

Or even:

```
>>> mask = (2**(ipaddress.IPV4LENGTH))-256
>>> y = ipaddress.ip_address(int(x) & mask)
```

Similarly, with an `IPv6Address` object:

```
>>> x = ipaddress.ip_address('1234::1')
>>> mask = (2**(ipaddress.IPV6LENGTH))-256
>>> y = ipaddress.ip_address(int(x) & mask)
>>> y
IPv6Address('1234::')
```

Here, we're setting `mask` to the "all ones" address `(2**129)-1)` and then setting the last octet to zero by subtracting `255`.